# Adding a new vertex and an edge to an existing vertex in Datastax CassandraCSharpDriver.Graph but get edge OUT error

Tags: c#, graph-databases, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

I'm adding a new vertex and an edge to an existing vertex in Datastax Graph, and I wanted to see how to do that with Datastax CassandraCSharpDriver.Graph.

The working Gremlin code looks like this:

```
Vertex link1 = graph.addVertex(label, "link").property("id", "link-2")
Vertex item1 = g.V().has("item", "id", "item-1").next()
item1.addEdge('contains', link1)
```

But in the C# driver syntax, I was hoping to do something like this but when I execute it, the error is the "adjacency of 'contains' in direction 'OUT' has not been added to 'link'"

```
GraphTraversalSource g = DseGraph.Traversal(mySession);
var traversal = g.AddV("link").Property("id", "link-1")
                .AddE("contains")
                .V("item").Has("id", Eq("item-1"));
GraphResultSet result = mySession.ExecuteGraph(traversal);
```

I had created the edge and edge connections like this:

```
schema.edgeLabel("contains").multiple().create()  
schema.edgeLabel("contains")  
.connection("item", "link")  
.connection("link", "item")  
.add()
```

Any ideas if the schema edge is setup incorrectly or how to do this the best way in Datastax CassandraCSharpDriver.Graph?

Comment: Can you post a complete example that I'm able to reproduce locally? I'm not able to run the gremlin queries at the moment.

Comment: The complete schema should be something like this, right?

`schema.propertyKey('id').Text().ifNotExists().create()
                schema.edgeLabel('contains').multiple().ifNotExists().create()
                schema.vertexLabel('item').properties('id').ifNotExists().create()
                schema.vertexLabel('link').properties('id').ifNotExists().create()
                schema.edgeLabel('contains').connection('item', 'link').connection('link', 'item').add()`

Comment: @JoãoReis yes, that's about right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Gremlin here:

```
g.AddV("link").Property("id", "link-1")
            .AddE("contains")
            .V("item").Has("id", Eq("item-1")
```

isn't properly formed. It should be:

```
g.AddV("link").Property("id", "link-1").As('l1').
  V("item").Has("id", Eq("item-1")).
  AddE('contains').To('l1')
```

With `AddE()` you need to specify the `From()` and the `To()` to identify the vertices that the edge is connecting. Without specifying those, `AddE()` will just use the incoming `Vertex` for both values creating a self-referencing edge. As a result in this case, you should only need to specify the `To()` as the `From()` is inferred.

Please note the examples in the [Reference Documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#addedge-step) where you should see other methods to doing this.

Comment: Thanks, I did something similar and I'll give you credit. I aliased both vertices, then used a "From" and "To" clause in the AddE. 
The exact syntax I used was more like:
g.AddV("link").Property("id", "link-1").As('l1').
  V("item").Has("id", Eq("item-1")).As('it1').
  AddE('contains').From('it1').To('l1')